# Even or Odd number in COBOL language

Tags: cobol

I am trying to write a function in COBOL language which check if number is even or odd and return accordingly. But instead, it shows error. This is my code:

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. EVEN-OR-ODD.
       DATA DIVISION.
       LINKAGE SECTION.
       01 NUM         PIC S9(08).
       01 R           PIC S9(08).
       01 Q           PIC S9(08).
       01 RESULT      PIC A(04).
       PROCEDURE DIVISION USING NUM.
         DIVIDE NUM BY 2 GIVING R REMAINDER Q.
         IF Q IS NOT EQUAL TO 0
         MOVE "ODD" TO RESULT
         ELSE
         MOVE "EVEN" TO RESULT
         STOP RUN.
       END PROGRAM EVEN-OR-ODD.
```

Instead of result either "EVEN" or "ODD", it raise an error:

```
attempt to reference unallocated memory (signal SIGSEGV)

 Last statement of EVEN-OR-ODD unknown
 Last statement of TESTS unknown
```

This is test I am using to check the code:

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. TESTS.
       DATA DIVISION.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01 NUM     PIC S9(8).
       01 RESULT  PIC A(4).
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
           TESTSUITE 'Fixed tests'.
           TESTCASE 'Test 01'.
           MOVE 0 TO NUM
           INITIALIZE RESULT
           CALL 'EVEN-OR-ODD' USING BY CONTENT NUM BY REFERENCE RESULT
           EXPECT RESULT TO BE "Even".
           TESTCASE 'Test 02'.
           MOVE 1 TO NUM
           INITIALIZE RESULT
           CALL 'EVEN-OR-ODD' USING BY CONTENT NUM BY REFERENCE RESULT
           EXPECT RESULT TO BE "Odd".
           TESTCASE 'Test 03'.
           MOVE 7 TO NUM
           INITIALIZE RESULT
           CALL 'EVEN-OR-ODD' USING BY CONTENT NUM BY REFERENCE RESULT
           EXPECT RESULT TO BE "Odd".
           TESTCASE 'Test 04'.
           MOVE -42 TO NUM
           INITIALIZE RESULT
           CALL 'EVEN-OR-ODD' USING BY CONTENT NUM BY REFERENCE RESULT
           EXPECT RESULT TO BE "Even".
           TESTCASE 'Test 05'.
           MOVE -17 TO NUM
           INITIALIZE RESULT
           CALL 'EVEN-OR-ODD' USING BY CONTENT NUM BY REFERENCE RESULT
           EXPECT RESULT TO BE "Odd".
           END TESTS.
       END PROGRAM TESTS.
```

Comment: See https://sourceforge.net/p/gnucobol/discussion/cobol/thread/ee0920be7e/  a bit different, but the debugging steps outlined in there would probably be a first step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
       DATA DIVISION.
       LINKAGE SECTION.
       01 NUM         PIC S9(08).
       01 R           PIC S9(08).
       01 Q           PIC S9(08).
       01 RESULT      PIC A(04).
       PROCEDURE DIVISION USING NUM.
```

which means 4 data items that are not in the program's storage - and only `NUM` getting data from the caller.

You get a memory error - very likely on the first use of any of those variables. Given the abort message this is GnuCOBOL, but you haven't enabled the runtime checks - recompiling with `cobc --debug EVEN-OR-ODD.cob` will likely lead to a more helpful diagnostic.

To actually fix this issue, change the `DATA DIVISION` to also have program-local storage:

```
       DATA DIVISION.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01 R           PIC S9(08).
       01 Q           PIC S9(08).
       01 RESULT      PIC A(04).
       LINKAGE SECTION.
       01 NUM         PIC S9(08).
       PROCEDURE DIVISION USING NUM.
```

(and I'd always highly suggest to compile with full runtime checks)

Comment: This helped, but I had to do further modification, not sure why, but it worked when also changed "STOP RUN." to "GOBACK."

Comment: `STOP RUN` is the equivalence of `exit(ret)` - so that's expected. Note that you can also use a `GOBACK` in the main program - it is what the COBOL standard "wants you to use", too.

Answer (score 0):

This code gave expected result:

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. EVEN-OR-ODD.
       DATA DIVISION.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01 R           PIC S9(08).
       01 Q           PIC S9(08).
       LINKAGE SECTION.
       01 NUM         PIC S9(08).
       01 RESULT      PIC A(04).
       PROCEDURE DIVISION USING NUM RESULT.
         DIVIDE NUM BY 2 GIVING R REMAINDER Q.
         IF Q IS NOT EQUAL TO 0
         MOVE "Odd" TO RESULT
         ELSE
         MOVE "Even" TO RESULT
         GOBACK.
       END PROGRAM EVEN-OR-ODD.
```